# How Git LFS works on large files?

Tags: git

I've tried to upload a large file of 1GB on the Github server using LFS.
It went fine. I though that since large binary files are not trackable like source code files, even a small modification should cost the entire upload once pushed, consequentely the bandwidth usage of 1 GB per push.
But, once pushed, I noticed that it was treated as a source code file, so the commit was made in an instant due to the small changes.
How is it possible? How Git LFS is so optimized even on large files?

Comment: LFS is short for "large file storage". You're asking _"How Git LFS is so optimized **even on large files**"_ but that's the whole point of LFS. You may want to revise the question (and do some more research on your own).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary blobs can still be broken down into blocks of any arbitrary amount, hashed, and then compared against a "known good" copy.

As a result it is entirely possible that minor modifications within or appends to a large file can result in changes to an amount equal to the hashed block size.

It is a technique similar to the system used by BitTorrent and is relevant to any system where files of unknown size need to be transferred over networks with minimal bandwidth usage when both parties *might* already have some parts of the file.

Comment: Could you please provide a link in order to see how it is implemented?
Thanks.